# Insert JSON into multiple tables on Database in Mule

Tags: json, mule, esb

I am trying to insert the contents of an JSON to a MySql database using Mule ESB. The JSON looks like:

> ```
> {
>  "id":106636,
>  "client_id":9999,
>  "comments":"Credit",
>  "salesman_name":"Salvador Dali", 
>  "cart_items":[
>               {"citem_id":1066819,"quantity":3}, 
>               {"citem_id":1066820,"quantity":10}
>             ]
> }
> ```

On mule I want to insert all data on a step like:

- Insert INTO order_header(id,client_id,comments,salesman_name)
- Insert INTO order_detail(id,citem_id,quantity)
- Insert INTO order_detail(id,citem_id,quantity)

Currently i have come this far on Mule:
[MuleSoft Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87CMK.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an excellant article here http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/2078/parse-json-keys-to-insert-records-into-postgresql-database-using-mule
that should be of help. You may need to modify as you need to write the order_header data first and then use a collection splitter for the order_detail and wrap the whole in a transaction.

Answer (score 2):

Use Bulk Execute operation of Database Connector.
You will insert into multiple tables.
for ex :

Query text

```
Insert INTO order_header(payload.id,payload.client_id,payload.comments,payload.salesman_name);
Insert INTO order_detail(payload.id,payload.cart_items[0].citem_id,payload.cart_items[0].quantity); etc..
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Since, you have already converted JSON into Object in the flow, you can refer individual values with their object reference like obj.id, obj.client_id etc.

1. Get a database connector next.
2. Configure your MySQL database in "Connector Configuration".
3. Operation: Choose "Bulk execute"
4. In "Query text" : Write multiple INSERT queries and pass appropriate values from Object (converted from JSON). Remember to separate multiple queries with semicolon (;) in Query text.

That's it !! Let me know if you face any issue. Hope it works for you..

Comment: I think I expressed myself poorly, the quantity of `cart_items`  if dynamic so i cant do a fixed query for the amount of `cart_items`.

Comment: Ok. Got it !!
So, The number of cart_items will determine the number of "INSERT" statements for ORDER_DETAIL table. Try this:
1. Have 1 DB connector post the JSONtoObject connector.
2. Add logic to use only 1 INSERT statement for ORDER_HEADER table.
3. Then, Add a "For each" component that will loop on the collection of cart_items. The Object from JSON should have a collection of cart_items.
4. Add another database component within "For each" and mention 1 INSERT statement for ORDER_DETAIL table. For each will automatically iterate over the cart_item collection and perform required "inserts".